# How can I inflate multiple menus into the options bar?

Tags: android-fragments, android-menu

(First off, I am using ActionbarSherlock via HoloEverywhere, although I don't know that this is related to the issue.)

I've got an activity with three fragments.  Each fragment has its own menu items and they all share some menu items.  I have already learned from StackOverflow that it is not permitted to add menu items in the Activity an then add more items in the `Fragment` (I had tried... it causes weird bugs).  So the `Activity` doesn't have a menu but each fragment does.  However, I'm still trying to avoid duplicating the menu entries in each fragment's menu xml.  To do this, I have one xml menu for each fragment and one xml menu that they all share.  For example, I have:

```
fragment_1_menu.xml
fragment_2_menu.xml 
all_fragments_menu.xml
```

and, in `Fragment1` I am trying to import both `fragment_1_menu.xml` and `all_fragments_menu.xml`:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_fragments_menu, menu);
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_1_menu, menu);
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

When I do this, it *almost* works, but, in my case, one of the menu items from `all_fragments_menu` is missing.  I don't mean its a blank hole in the menu... I mean its not represented in the menu at all.  The XML IDs are unique and map to different int's in the R.java.  It looks like it *should* work.  I do the same thing with `Fragment2` except that `fragment_2_menu.xml` has no items and, in that case, all menu items appear as expected.

Should this work?  Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured this out.  I had made a few mistakes and misunderstood the cause.  I needed to:

1. Change menu `showAsAction` terms to "always" in the XML (sigh).
2. Call menu.clear() at the beginning of `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.
3. Do 'something else' because, while this fixes the menu visually, buttons are not reporting presses properly.  The menu works fine until I rotate the device, at which point buttons stop working (although they look right).  But I think this is probably unrelated to the issue I reported.